# Can't access new ui members created using Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, designer, qt-designer

New members created in the UI Designer are not accessible in the class `Form`. I rebuilt the project and it's not working.

> error: 'class Ui::ViewUsers' has no member named 'btnUserImport'
>
> ui->btnUserImport->setIcon(ImportIcon);
>
> ```
>   ^
> ```

It's very strange because the old members are accessible.

Comment: Did you _run qmake_ before trying to build your project, if not, run it and then build your project.

Comment: Maybe your ui file is not properly rebuild? Try to delete your `ui_<yourfile>.h` and build again.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it unchecking the Shadow Build in the project build options, and then rebuild the project

Comment: You should not need to change the build type. Please revert to the shadow build, delete the build directory, and build again. It will work.